# ANGULAR 1.6 - Ionic 1 | Function params in controller different from params passed from ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic 1 application using angular 1.6. I have a dynamically generated template with 4 div inputs (phone 1 & phone 1 value, phone 2 & phone 2 value, ...) generated from ng-repeat. Each of these div has a delete button. On the ng-click, we pass to the controller some params including the current id of the phone we want to delete.

```
<button ng-click="my_delete_function(id)"></button>
```

So my first delete works just fine. However, on my second delete (for example : I've just deleted phone 1 and now I want to delete phone 2), the delete function in my controller keeps receiving old params. I verified in my HTML and even if I have the correct id "2" in my ng-click, the controller still receive id "1".

If I quit the view then I come back and try to delete again, the first time will again work until the next deletes where it would fail.

I've already tried

```
<ion-view cache-view="false">
...
</ion-view>
```

but this doesn't change anything.

Anyone has got any ideas on what could be happening?

**UPDATE 1**

I cannot post my entire template, but here is a simplified version :

template :

```
<div ng-repeat="phone on phones">
<p> phone.name </p> <button ng-click="delete(phone.id)">
</div>
```

controller function :

```
$scope.delete = function(id_phone){
// deleting procedure
}
```

This is in my controller where I receive the wrong id. The template however (my ng-click) sends the correct one.

Thank you for your help

**UPDATE 2 : PROBLEM SOLVED**

Solved my problem. I had "track by $index" on my ng-repeat. I removed it and now everything seems ok.

Comment: Can you post your template and controller code?

Comment: I cannot post my entire template, but here is a simplified version :

template :

    <div ng-repeat="phone on phones">
    <p> phone.name </p> <button ng-click="delete(phone.id)">
    </div>


controller function :

    $scope.delete = function(id_phone){
    // deleting procedure
    }

This is in my controller where I receive the wrong id. The template however (my ng-click) sends the correct one.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I am not sure why you have this bug but can you please try ng-repeat="phone on phones track by phone.id"

Comment: How do you know your ng-click sends the correct id if the one you receive in scope.delete is wrong? Maybe somehow you override id_phone after first deletion or your data gets corrupted during deletion process. I cannot say more unless I see more of your code. This one looks fine on its own

Comment: Ok so now it seems to work. I had "track by index" somewhere on my ng-repeat. By removing it everything deletions seem to work fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem. I had "track by $index" on my ng-repeat. I removed it and now everything seems ok.